# How to set color in a specific row in JTable

Tags: java, jtable

I would like to set color for specific rows in table.
I have implemented method getBadRows() which returns Map with keys (numbers of rows) which I'd like to highlight. Look at my code:

```
private static class WorkingTimeCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
                                                   boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        if (value instanceof Date) {
            value = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(value);
        }
        Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        WorkingTimeTableModel model = (WorkingTimeTableModel) table.getModel();

        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> r : model.getBadRows().entrySet()) {
            c.setForeground(row == Integer.parseInt(r.getKey()) ? Color.RED : Color.BLACK);
        }

        return c;
    }
}
```

When I have a four items in a Map for example, this method only highlights the last item in a Map. Previous items are not highlighted, because it looks like that it's always refreshed when call c.setForeground().

I would like to highlight rows which are stored in my Map. The key of Map corresponds with a index of row in the table.

I have no idea how to do that :( I've tried many ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a for loop at the end, but instead simply check if the row number in the getTableCellRendererComponent parameter matches one of the bad rows. If so, set the Color to red, if not to black.

Perhaps something like,

```
Color color = model.getBadRows().contains(row) ? Color.RED : Color.BLACK;
c.setForeground(color);
```